# Delete selected items from listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I want to do that but, the listbox changes on every deletion, so it throws runtime exception even if I tried to do a new object.

I tried like this:

```
ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection selectedItems = new ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection(lstClientes);
   selectedItems = lstClientes.SelectedItems;
if (lstClientes.SelectedIndex != -1)
{ 
    foreach (string s in selectedItems)
        lstClientes.Items.Remove(s);
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Debe seleccionar un email");
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can't modify a collection while iterating (using a `foreach`) through it.  Instead use a reverse `for` loop:

```
ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection selectedItems = new ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection(lstClientes);
selectedItems = lstClientes.SelectedItems;

if (lstClientes.SelectedIndex != -1)
{ 
    for (int i = selectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        lstClientes.Items.Remove(selectedItems[i]);
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Debe seleccionar un email");
```

Using a reverse loop ensures you don't skip over any after removing them.

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Thank you! 
just a little correction:

   for (int i = selectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; **i--**)

Comment: There could be a small bug if an item exists twice in the Items list and only the second one is selected. I think the first one might be removed. A solution with Items.RemoveAt(i) might be slightly better. But it will also be more important to have the iteration reversed!

Answer (score 13):

```
selectedItems = lstClientes.SelectedItems;
```

This line does not create a new collection, but sets a reference to the one in a listbox. So you are iterating through a collection and try to remove items from it at once. It is not possible

You could use this, for example:

```
foreach (string s in lstClientes.SelectedItems.OfType<string>().ToList())
   lstClientes.Items.Remove(s);
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't compile for me

Comment: @CristobalDeIncógnitoFlipo youm probablym needed to add `using System.Linq;` to your using list, as this code uses LINQ to objects

Comment: @CristobalDeIncógnitoFlipo Probably, the answer, you chose, is, say, more thrifty, as it doesn't create any extra collections. Nevertheless, LINQ is often both far more useful and quick then simple loops.

Comment: I hope to give a try to linq soon; syntax is too weird for me right now. So, I'm conditioned to choose the simpler, all just c# version, being loyal to the Keep-it-Simple principle and what I understand better. 
What I would think is that the simple loop will be often the faster. Anyway speed is not a matter this time... but I enjoy optimizations.
I really appreciate to have 2 valid choices, maybe will do speed test some day if the data in the list grows. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

Simple just like this:

```
while (lst.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
   lst.Items.Remove(lst.SelectedItems[0]);
}
```

Comment: This is brutal, but works OK for small N. These answers still miss anything closely elegant - which might have been some LINQ trick to extract the indexes and "reverse" the iterator (some `ToArray`, and then some magic...). Well, I'm afraid reverse comes only with .NET 4.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb358497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

```
lst.Items.Remove(lst.Items[lst.SelectedIndex]);
```

You can use this if you don't want to loop

Note: This only works to remove 1 item (multiple selections it will only remove the first selected item)

Answer (score 2):

To build on Patrick's answer I tend to use a reverse index removal as it retains the index of items pending removal while they're being removed without removing identical items.

```
private void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (listBox.SelectedIndex == -1) {
        return;
    }

    // Remove each item in reverse order to maintain integrity
    var selectedIndices = new List<int>(listBox.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>());
    selectedIndices.Reverse();
    selectedIndices.ForEach(index => listBox.Items.RemoveAt(index));
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. SelectedIndices seems the most convenient way of getting all the selected items.

Answer (score 1):

I found better solution.

```
        if (listBoxIn.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            while (listBoxIn.SelectedIndex!=-1)
            {
                listBoxIn.Items.RemoveAt(listBoxIn.SelectedIndex);                  
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code only answers are almost always too brief here.  Give some context to your answer.  In this case, as the question is very old, it is worth pointing out why your answer adds something extra to the accepted, upvoted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem today and wanted something a bit cleaner, and came up with this Linq solution:

```
foreach (int index in myListBox.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>().Select(x => x).Reverse())
    myListBox.Items.RemoveAt(index);
```

Basically the same as Patrick's solution of iterating backwards and removing selected items. However instead of iterating backwards, we reverse the list of items to remove and iterate forwards. We no longer iterate over the original enumeration, so we are allowed to remove items within the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most easiest way to remove selected items

```
 for(int v=0; v<listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; v++) {
            listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[v]);
        }
```

Comment: I cannot believe this answer is correct.  Wouldn't the SelectedItems list change every time an item is removed from the list?  And in that case, when you get to the V - 1 item to remove, the selected items list will only have one item, not V items.  The answer above, where you are always removing the zeroth item from the SelectedItems list, is correct.

Comment: What if someone has selected multiple items?

Answer (score 0):

This works for multiple and single selections in WPF.

```
while (xListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    xListBox.Items.RemoveAt(SavedItemsListBox.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a global variable:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Int32 index;
    }
```

Then at the selected index change save that index in the var you defined :

```
 private void lsbx_layers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           layerindex = lsbx_layers.SelectedIndices[0];//selected index that has fired the event
         }
```

Finally ,remove the element :

```
 lsbx_layers.Items.RemoveAt(Layerindex);
```